# Copy line UP/Down Issue in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, visual-studio-code, duplicates, copy, keyboard-shortcuts

When trying to copy a line (Up or Down) with:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd>/<kbd>↓</kbd>

Or:

- <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd>/<kbd>↓</kbd>

Nothing happens.